# Is there a way of showing a default image if there is no image uploaded?

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning Laravel by building a jobs project. I would like to display a default image/logo without adding a default on the database. I also have an Image resizer responsible for resizing logos.

Here is my controller:

```
$all_jobs = Job::latest()->paginate(8);
        $company_logo = new Image;

        // loop through jobs and resize image
        foreach ($all_jobs as $key => $jobs) {
            $all_jobs[$key]->ngo_logo = $company_logo->get_thumb('logos/'.$jobs->ngo_logo);
        }
        
        //dd($jobs->ngo_logo);

        $data['jobs'] = $all_jobs;
        return view('jobs.index', $data);
```

How do I get the default image which is in public/main/images/default.jpg to show up on the front end if no logo was uploaded? Thanks.

Comment: ‘$all_jobs[$key]->ngo_logo = $company_logo->get_thumb('logos/'.$jobs->ngo_logo)||asset(main/images/default.jpg);’

Comment: Im not quite sure how would you show images in public folder but after getting its link use ‘’’||’’’ as it would mean to return first part if its true and second part if first is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved without server side:

```
<img src="<?php echo "image.jpg"; ?>" onerror="this.src='default.jpg'">
```

Comment: Thanks  guys for the help. @IT goldman's solution worked well.