# Load image if it exists or load another image in Remix

Tags: mysql, reactjs, remix.run

I have a bunch of goods with (or without) photos.
I need to load image **if it exists** or show a common (like blank) image.
the stack is
**Remix**, **Prisma** and **mySQL** db.
Seems like storing images in mySQL is impossible (or is it?)
Also it seems like storing image path in db would be difficult in maintenance (or it is a solution? :D)
Here is what I tried:

```
 const getPicture= (path) => {
    try{
        const pic = require(`~/images/categories/${path}`)
        return pic;
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log('ERROR:', err)
        return noPic;
    }
  }
```

I tryed to put this code in page, tryed to put it in *loader*,
tryed to put pictures to a public or private folder
(without *~* in *require* path ofc)

when this runs in loader it says module not found (*path/to/image*)
when I run this in page code it says that dynamic require isn't supported.

How or how else can I achieve the goal?
I started react and js coding this January so, well, Im a noob :D

UPD:
thank you IT goldman, that was close!
Finally all works with

```
<img 
   src={'/path/in/public'} 
   onError={(e) => (e.target.onerror = null, e.target.src = anotherImg)}
/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way of showing a default image if there is no image uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72777522/3807365)

Comment: Nope, but its a duplicate of that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097560/react-js-replace-img-src-onerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try first

```
<img alt='' src={ '...'} onError={this.src='https://picsum.photos/200'}/>
```